# Matlab: Converting a double vector array to string cell array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, double, cell

```
map1 = containers.Map({'212','2','12','44'},[4,5,6,7]);
keyset = str2double(keys(map1));
```

Now I do a set of operations on the keyset which will give back

```
Keyset= [203,2,12,39];
```

I tired the following:

```
num2cell(num2str(keyset));
num2cell(num2str(keyset,1));
num2cell(num2str(keyset,'%11.0g'));
num2cell(num2str(keyset,3));
```

all of the above gave weird results in the final cell array. I just need the integers to be used as keys for another container map.

Comment: So what is your desired result? Is it `{'203', '2', '12', '39'}`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I propose 5 additional solutions, three of which are 4-5x faster by than the solutions proposed so far. The lessons learned from this are:

- `num2str` is slow
- `cellfun` and `arrayfun` can add significant overhead
- There are many ways to convert a numeric array to a cell array of strings.

The three highest-performance solutions are very similar in terms of performance:

Looping to assign cell elements

```
n4 = length(Keyset);
tmp4 = cell(n4,1);
for i4 = 1:n4
    tmp4{i4} = sprintf('%i',Keyset(i4));
end
```

Converting all to string and calling `textscan`

```
tmp6 = textscan(sprintf('%i\n',Keyset'),'%s');
tmp6 = tmp6{1};
```

Converting all to string and calling `regexp`.

```
tmp3 = regexp(sprintf('%i ',Keyset),'(\d+)','match');
```

---

Here's the full test code with timings:

```
function t = speedTest

t=zeros(7,1);
for ii=1:100, 
    Keyset=randi(1,10,100); % random keys
    tic; 
    eval( [ 'tmp1 = { ', sprintf(' %d ', Keyset), ' }; '] );
    t(1)=t(1)+toc; 
    tic;
    tmp2=arrayfun(@num2str, Keyset, 'Uniform', false);
    t(2)=t(2)+toc;

    tic;
    tmp3 = regexp(sprintf('%i ',Keyset),'(\d+)','match');
    t(3) = t(3)+toc;

    tic;
    n4 = length(Keyset);
    tmp4 = cell(n4,1);
    for i4 = 1:n4
        tmp4{i4} = sprintf('%i',Keyset(i4));
    end
    t(4) = t(4)+toc;

    tic;
    n5 = length(Keyset);
    tmp5 = cell(n5,1);
    for i5 = 1:n5
        tmp4{i5} = num2str(Keyset(i5));
    end
    t(5) = t(5)+toc;

    tic;
    tmp6 = textscan(sprintf('%i\n',Keyset'),'%s');
    tmp6 = tmp6{1};
    t(6) = t(6)+toc;

    tic;
    tmp7 = num2cell(Keyset);
    tmp7 = cellfun(@(x)sprintf('%i',x),tmp7,'uni',false);
    t(7) = t(7)+toc;


end;
t

t =

    1.7820
   21.7201
    0.4068
    0.3188
    2.2695
    0.3488
    5.9186
```

Comment: Yay, mine is the slowest! But how did we end up talking about performance here? :-)

Comment: @EitanT: It wasn't me! It was Shai who started it.

Comment: Just got the license server back. It works out great.. previously I also tried using sprintf('%11.0g',x). Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
arrayfun(@num2str, Keyset, 'Uniform', false)'
```

which should yield a 4-by-1 cell array for your example:

```
ans = 
    '203'
    '2'
    '12'
    '39'
```

Comment: @Shai not sure that the OP is looking for performance in this case.

Comment: this is why I added the "note" at the bottom - your solution is more "Matlab"ish than mine, but at a small cost of run-time...

Comment: @Shai I don't think it's more "Matlab"ish :) it's just shorter (and currently slower)

Comment: I am particularly font of all the `*fun` function: `cellfun`, `arrayfun`, `strcutfun` etc. I think they are more "Matlab"ish than evaluating an "on the fly" string... But maybe that's just me. Anyhow, +1 for nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
eval( [ 'NewKeySetStr = { ', sprintf(' %d ', Keyset), ' }; '] );
NewKeySetStr
```

I'm not sure this is the most elegant way to achieve the desired results, but it seems to work...

Comparing runtime with Eitan's solution:

```
t=zeros(2,1);
for ii=1:100, 
    Keyset=randi(1,10,100); % random keys
    tic; 
    eval( [ 'NewKeySetStr = { ', sprintf(' %d ', Keyset), ' }; '] );
    t(1)=t(1)+toc; 
    tic;
    tmp=arrayfun(@num2str, Keyset, 'Uniform', false);
    t(2)=t(2)+toc;
end;
t
```

Yields:

```
t =
   0.3986
   2.2527
```

It seems like proposed solution is faster.

Note: it seems like current implementation of `cellfun` is not optimized for speed. It is rumored that in future versions Mathworks intends to introduce better implementation of `cellfun`. So, Eitan's solution might not be optimal in current version, but it seems to be a good practice of Matlab skills.

Comment: +1: Even though your solution employs `eval`, it's still fast. However, I wonder if it works for very large arrays. By the way, I believe that `0.3s` differs from `2.2s` by approx. one order or magnitude (not two).

Comment: It is very difficult not to give you a -1 for an `evil` solution. Fortunately, there are at least 3 solutions that are faster.

Comment: The slip of tongue was not by chance... :)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to improve the regexp solution for large integers, using the split functionality.
Also I was somewhat misled by one of Jonas's solutions, which didn't evaluate all sprintf calls in the for loop.
Edit: also added the new 2016 string functionality suggested in the comments.

```
t = speedTest()

function t = speedTest

t=zeros(5,1);
for ii=1:100
    Keyset=randi(10000000,10,1000); % random keys

    tic;
    n4 = numel(Keyset); % changed to numel (length only gives number of columns)
    tmp1 = cell(n4,1);
    for i4 = 1:n4
        tmp1{i4} = sprintf('%i',Keyset(i4));
    end
    t(1) = t(1)+toc;

    tic;
    tmp2 = regexp(sprintf('%i ',Keyset),'(\d+)','match');
    t(2) = t(2)+toc;

    tic;
    tmp3 = regexp(sprintf('%i ',Keyset),' ','split');
    tmp3(end) = [];
    t(3) = t(3)+toc;

    tic;
    tmp4 = string(Keyset(:));
    t(4) = t(4)+toc;

    # test in case you want to go back to characters
    tic;
    tmp5 = char(string(Keyset(:)));
    t(5) = t(5)+toc;
end
end
```

The regexp solution with split yields slightly better performance, and the string method is even faster:

```
t =

    6.1916
    1.1292
    0.8962
    0.6671
    0.7523
```

Comment: Starting in 16b MATLAB has a string datatype. string(Keyset) is ~25% faster than your fastest case.

Comment: My initial experiment was using tmp4 = string(Keyset) which causes the destruction of the existing tmp4. When using a new variable, string(Keyset) is 40% faster than your fastest case.